# 7 month old cat throws up wet food

Tags: cats, behavior, vocalizations

He threw up twice in 7 hours, it looked like his wet food and one of his whole treats. He plays and runs around like normal. He has been purring a whole lot as well.

He ate his dry food from the slow release toy, but hasn't eaten more wet food. I saw him drink a bunch of water.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Is he current on all his vaccinations? Does he go outside? Does he have access to any poisons or foods that are toxic to cats? How is his stool? If the vomiting continues, he should see an veterinarian. Please report back.

Comment: He hasn't pooped since vomiting. He is an indoor cat and no access to toxins

Comment: My cat vomits if he eats too fast. I suggest trying to feed him the food in parts instead of all at once? Other than that it could be a health or a furball issue

Answer (score 4):

Keep an eye on him! He might be having an off day. If you notice in the next couple of days that he's eating/drinking significantly less or that he's losing weight (weigh him daily if you can until you're no longer concerned) then bring him in for a checkup. Take note that 1-2 lbs. is quite a bit of weight for a cat to lose.

Another thing is that if a cat throws up multiple times in a month, there is something wrong, whether it be dietary allergies or eating too much fur. Some people will think it's normal for cats to vomit on occasion, but it is not.

Comment: Talk to the vet he said it's normal